# Get bigdelim effect with tabularray

Tags: braces, tabularray, bigdelim

Simply I would like to include braces across multiple rows within a table using tblr environment in the same way as bigdelim allows in a tabular environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the TeX code you have tried so far ...

Comment: For information, you should have a look at `nicematrix` and its command `\SubMatrix`.